# Mysql / PHP - Select a table name which contains a part of word

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Nice_Foo
Nice_table
Ugly_Foo
Ugly_table
Pretty_table
Pretty_Foo
```

What I am looking for is a method that selects the tables that contain `Foo` in the name.

Obviously there is more than one table so I need to select the first and then output its content, select second and so on.

I know basic SQL query to select a specific table, but not how to select if a substring is present in the name.

The result should equal the combination of these statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Nice_Foo; 
SELECT * FROM Ugly_Foo; 
SELECT * FROM Pretty_Foo;
```

Comment: You cannot do this with your current database, you have to query "mysql" database in your server to get information about tables.

Comment: Note that this kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: Unless these tables are *related* then there's nothing a *relational database* like MySQL can do to help. You have to do that yourself with a `UNION`. You need to organize your data using a proper [database normalization form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for your database to be able to work with you instead of against you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the name of the tables that have 'Foo' in its name:

```
show tables like '%Foo%';
```

Comment: uhmm... this coul be for me. I could use this code to print the tabless that contain name and then assign the names to an array with PHP

Comment: Is this what you need? I've seen the question have changed.

Comment: what return the code you posted? Could be printed with an echo or what?

Comment: This is just the query you can get this from php and print it with echo, iterate over the results or use it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for the same

```
    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '+TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Foo%'
```